# feature selection after extraction process

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I read that it is recommended to use `feature selection` after `feature extraction` process.

But there is something missing in all the posts I read:

- Suppose we have 50 features.
- Suppose we use feature extraction and we got 3 new extraction features

2 questions:

1. Do we need to run the `feature selection` on:

   - The 3 extracted features ?

   or

   - total 53 features (base 50 features + 3 extracted features) ?
2. Suppose we run feature selection on the result of feature extraction and not all the new extracted features where chosen (i.e 2 out of 3) by feature selection algorithm, 
   it seems that the output of feature extraction was not good enough if we can drop one of the 'new' dimension ?

Answer (score 1):

1. We run feature_selection on the full original feature set to select the most useful features.

   If you used dimensionality reduction to find 3 additional features, then your feature set will consist of all the 53 features, hence you will run feature selection on the 53 features.
2. This seems more like a statement than a question. If you mean, **we can re-run feature extraction (dimensionality reduction) with 1 less feature as one of the features was not important. No, you can't make this assumption that re-running the extraction with 2 features will ensure that both of them are being selected.** It all depends on what dimensionality reduction technique is being used, what is the feature selection scheme, the dataset, etc.